# Spring @Transactional(propagation = propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) doesn't work if stream is open?

Tags: spring, transactions, stream, jboss, wildfly

It's going to be hard to provide example code on this one.  Let me try to explain it with some pseudo code.  If I need to, I'll have to put together a working example.

First I'll demonstrate a variation of the code that works as expected.  In this variation I'm iterating over a List of entities.  For each entity I call a service method which creates a new transaction and writes something to the DB.  If an exception occurs, all the work done in that service method remains in the database as expected because the work was done in new transactions that are independent of the outer transaction.

Here's the pseudo code for the class/method that is iterating over a List of entities and calling a service method for each one.

```
@Transactional
public myMethod()
{
     List<MyEntity> myEntities = myRepo.findAllBySomething("foo");

     foreach(MyEntity myEntity : myEntities)
     {
          myService.doSomeWork()
     }
}
```

Here is the service method that creates a new transaction to do some work.

```
@Service
public MyService {

     @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
     public void doSomeWork() {
       SomeOtherEntity someOtherEntity = new SomeOtherEntity();
       ...
       someOtherRepo.save(someOtherEntity);
     }
}
```

The above example works as expected.  If an exception is encountered, all the work done in the MyService.doSomeWork() calls is retained in the database because it was done in independent transactions.

Here's where the problem comes in.  The number of entities I'm iterating over is very large and was causing memory issues.  So instead of retrieving them in a list I changed the code to use a Stream.  The repo was changed to return Stream instead of List and the code changed to look something like this...

```
@Transactional
public myMethod()
{
     try (Stream<MyEntity> myStream = myRepo.findAllBySomething("foo")) {

          // Get an iterator to allow us to step through each row.
          Iterator<MyEntity> myStreamIterator = myStream.iterator();

          // Loop through each row
          while (myStreamIterator.hasNext()) {
               // Get the next row
               MyEntity myEntity = myStreamIterator.next();

               myService.doSomeWork();

          }
     }
}
```

Now if an exception is thrown, the work done in all the MyService.doSomeWork() calls is not in the database! It's very strange.  I have turned on trace logging for org.springframework.transaction.  In both instances of the code I can see a new transaction being created on each call to MyService.doSomeWork().  But when the exception is thrown, for some reason the inserts done in MyService.doSomeWork() are lost in the Stream based version but not in the List based version.

Is this known behavior that if you create a new transaction while a stream is open that it's somehow tied to that outer transaction? Or is this possibly a Spring bug?

Comment: Why the iterator? JUst use `myStream.forEach ( (myEntity) -> myService.doSomeWork(myEntity))`. Also shouldn't you be passing the other entity into this method, feels weird to retrieve some entity and not pass it along. If so please provide some actual (or at least matching code).

Comment: Yes, I could have used a foreach and a lambda but that isn't really material to the issue.  Whether or not I pass the entity into this particular service method is also completely immaterial to the issue.  I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible.  In my real implementation I have thousands and thousands of lines of code and much more complex transaction boundaries with some work being done as part of the outer transaction that we do want rolled back on failure and some of the work being done in new transactions that we do not want rolled back on failure.

Comment: I will work on an actual simple working example.  But the fact remains, if a stream is open there is unexpected behavior that new transactions appear to be rolled back with the outer transaction when there is an exception.

Comment: That shouldn't happen if that is an actual external method call, now if you are calling the method on the same class that would be the case. And passing around objects does matter, especially if you are starting to cross EntityManager boundaries because int he end that is what is happening.

Comment: The call to the method that creates a new transaction is in a different service class.  I know the issue you are referring to.  I'm not bypassing the proxy by calling a method directly in the same class.  The example is very close to what we are doing.  We are not passing the entity class into that service call that creates the new transaction.  We have application log tables in our DB.  We want these "logs" kept in the DB even if the main transaction is rolled back.  So it would literally be something like 'logService.dbLog("Starting processing of XXXXX")'.  The entity is not being passed in.

Comment: I'm working on a complete standalone working example of the issue.  It will also be much easier for me to test this using different versions of Spring Boot to see if this issue was fixed at some point.  Our application is on Spring Boot 2.3.3. currently.

Comment: Here's an interesting twist.  I wrote test code to demonstrate the issue.  If I run it as standalone Spring Boot it works as expected.  If I run the same code under JBoss I get the issue.  Ugh!  

I vaguely remember seeing some Spring issues related to new transactions and JBoss but they were very old.  If I remember correctly the Spring folks were saying it wasn't their issue, it was a peculiarity on how JBoss was handling database connections in relation to starting a new transaction.  I'll start looking at it from that perspective.

Comment: Ah you left out the part that you aren't using the embedded container but a JEE container. Which probably also means you are using a server managed datasource and transactionmanager?

Comment: Yes, we are using a container managed datasource and transaction manager.  We have a middleware team that manages the JBoss configuration.  But if there is anything you think I should look at from that perspective, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: How things behave in a JEE server depends an multiple factors. I stayed away from them from a long time (and intend to keep it that way I hope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small piece of code to illustrate this issue.  This made it easier for me to test and pinpoint the problem.  What I found was when running this code in a standalone Spring Boot application, everything worked as expected.  When I deployed the code to a JBoss server, the problem occurs.

I was able to come up with a resolution to the issue.  I suspect this is more of a work-around than a fix.  But the problem seems to be with JBoss's "Cached Connection Manager".  It is enabled by default on the datasource.  Turning off the "Cached Connection Manager" fixes the issue.  I found some older issues where the Spring folks blame the Cached Connection Manager for some transactional problems.  I'm probably going to submit tickets to both Redhat and Spring for the issue and see if anyone wants to step up and be accountable.  I doubt either will, but at very least hopefully I can provide some visibility to the next poor soul who runs into this mess.

Until someone gets to the bottom of the issue, to turn off the Cached Connection Manager, update your datasource and set use-ccm to "false" like this...

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/myDs" pool-name="myDs" use-ccm="false">
```

or similarly for an XA datasource...

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/myXaDs" pool-name="myXaDs" use-ccm="false">
```